# Transforming a code to Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have an array of NSNumbers that have to pass thru 20 tests. If one test fails than the array is invalid if all tests pass than the array is valid. I am trying to do it in a way that as soon as the first failure happens it stops doing the remaining tests. If a failure happens on the 3rd test then stop evaluating other tests.

I am trying to convert the code I have that is serial processing, to parallel processing with grand central dispatch, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

This is what I have.

First the definition of the tests to be done. This array is used to run the tests.

Every individual test returns YES when it fails and NO when it is ok.

```
#define TESTS  @[         \
    @"averageNotOK:",     \
    @"numbersOverRange:", \
    @"numbersUnderRange:",\
    @"numbersForbidden:", \
    // ... etc etc
    @"numbersNotOnCurve:"]


- (BOOL) numbersPassedAllTests:(NSArray *)numbers {

  NSInteger count = [TESTS count];

  for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {

    NSString *aMethodName = TESTS[i];

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(aMethodName);

        BOOL failed = NO;

        NSMethodSignature *signature = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];

        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        [invocation setSelector:selector];
        [invocation setTarget:self];
        [invocation setArgument:&numbers atIndex:2];
        [invocation invoke];


        [invocation getReturnValue:&failed];

        if (failed) {
          return NO;
        }
  }
  return YES;

}
```

This work perfectly but perform the tests sequentially.

How do I do that perform these tests in parallel executing the less amount of tests as needed?

Comment: your `TESTS` macro is so terrible....

Comment: yes I know, I hate it too, but this is still being developed. What do you suggest?

Comment: `SEL TESTS[] = {@selector(averageNotOK:)};`

Comment: ah, do you mean creating a C array of selectors? OK, I will try that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've spotted `dispatch_apply` which is the trivial parallel for. You've realised it can't do an early exit. Hence the question.

I'm afraid the answer is you'll need to do some bookkeeping for yourself, but luckily it shouldn't be too hard. To avoid repeating what you've got, pretend I'd turned the stuff inside your loop into:

```
BOOL failedTest(int);
```

So your serial loop looks like:

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {

    if(failedTest(i))
      return NO;
}

return YES;
```

Then you might do:

```
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

volatile __block int32_t hasFailed = 0;
dispatch_apply(
    count, 
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), 
    ^(size_t i)
    {
        // do no computation if somebody else already failed
        if(hasFailed) return;
        if(failedTest(i))
            OSAtomicIncrement32(&hasFailed);
    });

return !hasFailed;
```

So it'll keep starting tests until one of them has previously failed. The `OSAtomicIncrement32` just ensures atomicity without requiring a mutex. It'll usually turn into a cheap single instruction. You could get away with just using a `BOOL` as atomicity isn't really going to be a problem but why not just do it properly?

EDIT: also, you could just use `@selector` directly and create an array of selectors rather than using `NSSelectorFromString` with an array of strings, to save lookup time. If your tests are really cheap then consider doing them part serial, part parallel by having the `dispatch_apply` do, say, `count/10` dispatches and having each dispatch do 10 tests. Otherwise GCD will just issue `count` instances of the block and issuing has an associated cost.

Comment: wow, your code is melting my brain! Lets see if I understand that. hasFailed is an integer but you are using it as boolean and incrementing it with that exoteric command OSAtomicIncrement32 (why not 64? I am developing for mavericks). When this variable is 1, kaput, end. My question is this. In my case `numbersPassedAllTests:` is called from another part of the code and what about this code of yours? Do I put it inside a method returning a BOOL? How do I call it from another part of the code?

Comment: continuation.. what about this bookkeeping you mention, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, just that you're manually keeping track of `hasFailed`, with all subsequent blocks still being dispatched but opting not to do any work if someone else has already announced that they failed. Yeah, chuck it into a function or whatever for calling from wherever.

Comment: I am sorry I don't see how your code could work using dispatch_apply if you are using it to replace my loop, unless you want me to use this structure as the structure of every test I am doing. Is that what you mean? If it is not, than I don't see how I can fit my loop there.

Comment: `dispatch_apply` is a parallel for loop. It can directly replace any standard `for` loop. So, yes, you'd use it like that.